# How to restore viewer state directly from MarkupEdit or MarkupView mode?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, markup-extensions

With reference of https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/playing-with-the-new-view-data-markup-api.html, I am implementing 2D markup feature in forge viewer.

I'm using Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore library to draw annotations over model in forge viewer. For that I'm loading Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore extension as _markupsExtension .

I tried drawing some markup annotation and saved viewer state. When I tried loading these previously drawn annotations, It **failed to restore viewer state**, but it was loading annotations data properly.

```
// To draw and save markup 
viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore").then(function(markupExt) {
    _markupsExtension = markupExt;
    _state = _markupsExtension.viewer.getState();

    _markupsExtension.hide();
    _markupsExtension.enterEditMode();

    //From now on, while in EditMode, the user will be drawing text boxes

    _data = _markupsExtension.generateData(); //Annotations data can be generated
    _state = _markupsExtension.viewer.getState(); //to store viewer state information
    _markupsExtension.leaveEditMode();

    viewer.unloadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore"); //User can navigate within model
});


// To load previously drawn markup
viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore").then(function(markupExt) {
    _markupsExtension = markupExt;

    _markupsExtension.leaveEditMode();
    _markupsExtension.show();

    _markupsExtension.viewer.restoreState(_state); //it fails to restore state
    _markupsExtension.viewer.impl.invalidate(true);

    _markupsExtension.loadMarkups(_data, 'aaa'); //loads markup data while keeping viewerstate unchanged.
});
```

- Why does it fail to restore state while being **in markup viewing mode**?
- What is difference between **_markupsExtension.viewer.restoreState**(_state) and **viewer.restoreState**(_state)

**================================ EDITED =============================**

Is there any way where I could stay within editing mode/viewing mode and change viewer's state?

I am saving all markups in a list view in different sessions or file per session (referring https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/playing-with-the-new-view-data-markup-api.html ).
e.g. 1) I moved model to the top and drawn arrow pointing to particular object and I saved it with name "MarkupA.json".
2) I moved model to front and zoomed it out so that it went far from camera. Then I drawn Square markup and stored it with name "MarkupB.json".
3) Then again I kept model to default iso (home) mode and drawn text annotation and saved it with name "MarkupC.json".

All these markups are listed in the UI panel like a tree. So when am clicking on any particular name, that markup and its model viewer state has to get restored without change in any markup mode.

I have checked this similar functionality in bim360. When I stored different markups in BIM360, it stored all markups in its database and small thumbnail screenshot appeared for its relevant markup card. I viewed all markups in markup panel or comment panel.

When I clicked on specific thumbnail, every markup appeared with appropriate stored viewer state.

I am trying to get similar functionality in forge viewer using new Markups core extension and customised its markup code to store states with markups. When I tried to load each markup, it seems like markup is getting loaded but its viewer state is not able to get restored neither in edit mode nor in viewing mode. I understood that restoring state is not possible if we are in markups mode. But what if I want to show the previously stored drawn markup on particular view?

The workaround which I tried to switch between markup is as follow,

On click of another markup -

a) leave viewing mode

b) restore model with stored state

c) enter viewing mode.

d) load its markup svg.

- The issue with this is it is taking too much time taking too much time to reload markup with restored state.

Can you please tell me if we have any other workaround or approach to achieve loading and restoring markup and its viewer state synchronously?

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it fail to restore state while being in markup viewing mode?

When in markup mode the camera is locked so you will need to drop out of edit mode before restoring Viewer states and then go back.

> What is difference between _markupsExtension.viewer.restoreState(_state) and viewer.restoreState(_state)

No difference as `_markupsExtension.viewer` is just a reference of the plugin to the master Viewer object

Comment: Hello Bryan, I have edited the question and added my findings and workaround which I tried. Can you please hep me on this?

Comment: Unfortunately for now that's probably the best (and only) approach - stay tuned to our [forge blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog) for updates on future releases because this might get addressed in upcoming versions soon