# viewer.restoreState not working in Markup View Mode

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to get the restoreState method working when we are using MarkupsCore and currently in ViewMode. The idea to load the previously saved markup file (.svg) and the viewstate (.json) at the time of creating the markup, however the markup data gets loaded, however restoreState doesn't work.
I have the similar issue as described here: [How to restore viewer state directly from MarkupEdit or MarkupView mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56022664/how-to-restore-viewer-state-directly-from-markupedit-or-markupview-mode)

Here is the code:

```
_markupExtension.leaveEditMode();
_markupExtension.hide();
_markupExtension.viewer.restoreState(_state); //previously stored state in a file
_markupExtension.show("" + layerId + "");
_markupExtension.loadMarkups(_data,"" + layerId + "");
```

Please help. Thanks very much!

Comment: is restorestate workng normally before editmode on or off?

Comment: Yes, it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for viewer.restoreState to finish before load markups. You can follow instructions from the link below. I'm successful with it.

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/wait-restorestate-finish